# Check value of local variable assigned with let/let* editing org-export functions

Tags: debugging, let-binding, local-variables

On my way learning emacs and doing some first steps in elisp programming, I'm trying to adapt the LaTeX output of org-export. It's a lot learning by doing and that's a good thing since it improves my skills step by step.

But since some of the functions defined in `oy-latex.el` are quite complex, it would be great to check the values of some local variables/symbols assigned with `let` or `let*` after I modified the code, so I can see if my edits were correct.

For example the function `org-latex--caption/label-string` assigns the text named with `#+caption:` in the org-file to the local variable `main` (using another function `org-export-get-caption`):

```lisp
(let* ((label (org-latex--label element info nil t))
       (main (org-export-get-caption element)) ;; this line!
       (attr (org-export-read-attribute :attr_latex element))
       [...]
```

How can I check the current value of the symbol/variable `main` after e.g. I edited the definition. Since the value is only locally assigned and the function is only invoked when I export with **C-c C-e l p**, I don't know any way to access the value. But it would be of great help to debug my edits and find possible errors.

I'm aware that there might be a simple solution, but couldn't find one so far; mainly due to my very minimal knowledge of emacs lisp. Thus, any help is very appreciated!

(Of course, I do not change anything in the `ox-latex.el` itself but only in a custom package which is loaded locally.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly, but you can always `wrap` the value with a `print`, i.e. `(print (org-export-get-caption element))`. Print does not alter the 'original' return value.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're modifying the code, you have many options.

You can log messages with the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `message` function.  That's super simple.  View the `*Messages*` buffer with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

You can `defvar` some permanent variable and `setq` it to the value of the `let`-bound value while it's still bound, so that you can inspect it later with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>.

You could `(debug)` in the code to drop into the normal debugger at that point, or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `debug-on-entry` for the function, or instrument the function definition for edebug to step through the function when it's called.  Regardless of how you debug, you can then inspect values as you step through the code.  You can read all about the debuggers in the elisp manual: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Debugging` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the hints. I'll try some of your suggestions. Which way would you prefer personally?

Comment: "It depends" -- whichever gets me the result with the least effort basically.  Probably either `message` or using one of the debuggers in practice.  Try them all.  Using the debuggers is the most complex suggestion, but having a basic familiarity with those is very valuable, so I recommend doing that regardless of the current problem.

Comment: @lukeflo If you found phils' answer helpful, you should mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @PhilHudson I know. I'm still testing the different ways and will share my experience soon.

Comment: I find `edebug` more user friendly than regular `debug`. It steps through the function showing every value. Nevertheless, it can take some time. Couldn't get it to go with logging the value as message which seems to be the less complicated way. Might have to take a more detailed look into the docs...

Comment: That's very odd -- if you've added `(message "Value is %S" varname)` to the code and you're not getting any messages from that, my only explanation is that the form is not being evaluated.  Reasons for *that* could be "it's in the wrong place", or maybe "you forgot to evaluate the modified function definition".  It's hard to say, though.